# Firebase Analytics overcounting users?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

all. It looks like our Firebase analytics integration is not working as expected - we have approximately 20 users of our app, but Firebase reports over 1K.

I suspect this has to do with setting the user ID appropriately. But I'm not sure what I've done wrong - we call FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance().setUserId whenever a user signs in.

Are we supposed to call this more frequently? Say, whenever the app is opened? Am I missing some way to associate our users with their IDs in Firebase? Or am I misunderstanding something altogether?

Comment: Users in Firebase are device users. Are you talking about users with accounts? One account may be used on multiple apps and it may looks as if there are more users than the number of accounts.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean here. To be more clear, we have a server-based ID scheme for our users. The server provides an ID whenever a user signs in to the app. We then call "setUserId" with that value. But it looks like Firebase has ended up counting far more users than our server reports, which is very strange - this app hasn't been released yet, so I know there aren't that many installs.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem here, for any future searchers. The issue was the pre-launch report generated by the Google Play Console. This is causing many anonymous sessions to be reported to Firebase, since the apps are installed/reinstalled many times. This artificially inflates your user count if you are doing something like continuous deployment.

Comment: That's what I meant in the comment above. Whenever you install/uninstall the app, you will appear as a new user as the data has been swiped when you uninstall the app.